# how can i add another toolbar in firefox?

Tags: firefox, toolbar

i have one line in my brower in which i can add sites for quick surfing.
i tried to add a new blank line (by customize the tool bar, in the menu pop up by right click on the tool bar) because the first one is full but i couldn't do so because the blank one didn't enter and disappeared.
what can i do to solve this?
yishai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the Bookmarks Toolbar? There are add-ons that can make more efficient use of the space, like "Smart Bookmarks": https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4072/

This allows hiding bookmark names and showing only favicons, changing the spacing between the bookmarks, etc.

Comment: i think this is it. thanks alot!  small problem, when there is an icon for the shortcut it doesn't display the title of the site.